# Connection pooling jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection, connection-pooling

you can see here we are using our own internal connection pool, not using commons.dcbp connection pool so changing the connection settings in the server xml does not do anything. what is the best way to handle testing/removing stale connections? is it better to do a validation query in the getConnection() method or is it better to just remove the connections from the connection pool after a certain amount of time(and how would you do this)?

```
//working connection

[18 Mar 23:19:01] (ajp-nio-8701-exec-5) INFO : pconn: com.peregrine.esf.jdbc.PoolableConnection@782d14dd pconn.isStreamOpen(): true

//after about an hour, tries to grab same connection from pool but it is already closed by db
[19 Mar 00:26:19] (ajp-nio-8701-exec-1) INFO : pconn: com.peregrine.esf.jdbc.PoolableConnection@782d14dd pconn.isStreamOpen(): true
[19 Mar 00:26:19] (ajp-nio-8701-exec-1) ERROR: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection reset
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection reset
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:74)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:131)
    at  


public final class DefaultConnectionPool implements ConnectionPool
{
    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DefaultConnectionPool.class);

    private Connector mConnector;

    /** Maximum number of connections to allow. */
    private final int mMaxConn;

    /** Number of open connections. */
    protected int mOpen;

    /** List of unused, open connections. */
    private final LinkedList mConns = new LinkedList();

    /** Count of threads wait for a connection. */
    private int mWaiting;

    private int mWaitInfo;

    private int mWaitWarn;

    private final int mThreshold;

    public DefaultConnectionPool(Connector connector, int poolSize)
    {
        mConnector = connector;
        mMaxConn   = poolSize;

        mThreshold = Math.max( 1, mMaxConn );
    }

    public PoolSnapshot getSnapshot()
    {
        PoolSnapshot p = new PoolSnapshot();

        p.mMaxConn = mMaxConn;
        p.mOpen    = mOpen;
        p.mWaiting = mWaiting;
        p.mIdle    = mConns.size();

        return p;
    }

    private StringBuffer buildWaitingMessage()
    {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(100);

        buffer.append( Integer.toString( mWaiting ) );
        buffer.append( " thread(s) waiting for one of " );
        buffer.append( Integer.toString( mMaxConn ) );
        buffer.append( " pooled connections" );

        return buffer;
    }

    /**
     * Return a connection that we're finished with back to the pool.
     * @param conn
     */
    public synchronized void returnToPool( final Connection conn )
    {
        if (conn != null)
            mConns.add( conn );
        notifyAll();
    }

    /**
     * Create a new PoolableConnection decorating a real connection.
     * @param conn
     * @throws java.sql.SQLException
     * @return
     */
    synchronized protected PoolableConnection create( final Connection conn )  throws SQLException
    {
        PoolableConnection pconn = new PoolableConnection( conn );
        mOpen++;
        return pconn;
    }

    /**
     * Destroy a poolable connection.
     * @param conn
     */
    synchronized public void destroy( final Connection conn )
    {
        if (conn instanceof PoolableConnection)
        {
            PoolableConnection pConn = (PoolableConnection) conn;

            if (pConn.getPool() == this)
            {
                mOpen--;
                pConn.destroy();
                notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }

    synchronized public Connection recycle(final Connection conn) throws SQLException
    {
        if (conn instanceof PoolableConnection)
        {
            PoolableConnection pConn = (PoolableConnection) conn;

            if (pConn.getPool() == this)
            {
                pConn.destroy();
                pConn = null;

                Connection newConn = mConnector.getConnection();
                if (newConn != null)
                {
                    PoolableConnection p = new PoolableConnection( newConn );
                    p.open(this);
                    return p;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get a pooled connection, or wait for one to become available.
     * @throws java.sql.SQLException
     * @return
     */
    synchronized public Connection getConnection()  throws SQLException
    {
        log.info("...getdefaultconnection");
        PoolableConnection pconn;
        log.info("mConns.size(): "+mConns.size()+" mOpen: "+mOpen+" mMaxConn: "+mMaxConn);
        // do we need to wait?
        if (mConns.isEmpty() && (mOpen == mMaxConn))
        {
            mWaiting++;
            try
            {
                // do we want to warn?
                if (mWaiting >= mMaxConn)
                {
                    // did we hit logging threshhold?
                    if ((mWaitWarn % mThreshold) == 0)
                    {
                        log.info( buildWaitingMessage() );
                    }

                    mWaitWarn++;
                    mWaitInfo++;
                }

                // else, we want to inform
                else
                {
                    // did we hit logging threshhold?
                    if ((mWaitInfo % mThreshold) == 0)
                    {
                        log.info( buildWaitingMessage() );
                    }

                    mWaitInfo++;
                }

                // wait while max connections are in use
                while (mConns.isEmpty() && (mOpen == mMaxConn))
                {
                    try { wait(250); }  catch( InterruptedException ignored )  {}
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // done waiting.  Reset counters if necessary
                mWaiting--;
                if (mWaiting == 0)
                {
                    mWaitInfo = 0;
                    mWaitWarn = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        // get a connection
        if (mConns.isEmpty())
        {
            Connection conn = mConnector.getConnection();
            pconn = create( conn );
        }
        else
        {
            pconn = (PoolableConnection) mConns.removeFirst();
            log.info("pconn: "+pconn+" pconn.isStreamOpen(): "+pconn.isStreamOpen());
        }

        pconn.open( this );
        return pconn;
    }

    public synchronized void shutDown()
    {
        log.debug("DefaultConnectionPool shutting down...");
        Iterator itor = mConns.iterator();
        while (itor.hasNext())
        {
            PoolableConnection conn = (PoolableConnection)itor.next();
            conn.destroy();
            log.debug("Connection [" + conn.toString() + "] shutdown.");
            conn = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason _why_ you're not using a connection pool library? The current implementation seems quite complex and also it's difficult to understand what is your exact problem.

Comment: i couldnt tell you why, its just how it was. basically if you read the comments in the code, it returns a connection back to the pool, then after a certain amount of time the connection goes stale but it doesnt get removed from the pool causing connection reset error

Answer (score 1):

It is common for connection pooling frameworks to offer the following settings/facilities along the lines of what you are talking about:

1. maxIdleTime - Maximum time a connection can sit in the pool without being accessed before it is closed and removed from the pool
2. idleConnectionTestPeriod - How frequently to test an idle connection to verify it is still open and valid
3. preferredTestQuery - Query to use to test if a connection is connected and valid (For example: `Select 1` - used for SQLServer).

Most frameworks have settings like these (and many others). You should research a couple of common ones to compare and get informed.

As far as how they are implemented. Typically the framework will have 1 or more threads running in the background to perform the checks and do cleanup. In fact often the number of threads allocated for this is also configurable.

You should really consider migrating to a formal, well tested framework. Trying to reinvent the wheel in this case will likely never achieve stable results when compared to frameworks that are widely used.

If you must continue to use your own home-baked framework. My guess would be you are resistant to changing the API of everyone accessing your pool class. You could ease the pain of transition by configuring one of these frameworks within your application and 'bridge' the API by altering the internals of your `DefaultConnectionPool` class to delegate to the one provided by the framework.